# How to port forward Nomad task from Consul?

Tags: devops, consul, nomad

I want to debug a container on my host machine instead of from within the container (so I have stuff like curl and other software). K8S has the functionality to port-forward a container, how is it achievable with consul?

Comment: How is connecting to host machine running a service related to port forwarding? How does it work in kubernetes?